# react-native-table-component use state to render table data

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, react-native-table-component

I'm using [react-native-table-component](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component) to render a table in react-native where I need to display data I receive from my server, hence it changes frequently.

The examples only show data hard coded into each row and I need it to be updated as soon as new data is pushed to the client.

**Code example**

```js
export default class ExampleTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['', 'Head1', 'Head2', 'Head3'],
      tableTitle: ['Title', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4'],
      tableData: [
        ['1', '2', '3'],  //data I need to be dynamic
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c']
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <TableWrapper style={styles.wrapper}>
            <Col data={state.tableTitle} style={styles.title} heightArr={[28,28]} textStyle={styles.text}/>
            <Rows data={state.tableData} flexArr={[2, 1, 1]} style={styles.row} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          </TableWrapper>
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**Code from react-native-table-component**

```js
{
  data.map((item, i) => {
    const height = heightArr && heightArr[i];
    return (
      <Row
        key={i}
        data={item}
        widthArr={widthArr}
        height={height}
        flexArr={flexArr}
        style={style}
        textStyle={textStyle}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, i am assuming you have to poll the server after certain interval and update your screen you could something like this :

**Poll after certain time interval**

```
        constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
           tableHead: ['', 'Head1', 'Head2', 'Head3'],
           tableTitle: ['Title', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4'],
           tableData: [ ],
          keepPolling: true
        }

        componentWillMount()
        {
          pollAfter(60 * 1000, ()=>{
            // get your data from the server here 
          }).then((response)=>{
           // and set state here like this
           this.setState({
             tableData : response
             });
          })
        }

        pollAfter(intervalDuration, fn) {
            const asyncTimeout = () => setTimeout(() => {
                this.pollAfter(intervalDuration, fn);
            }, intervalDuration);
            const assignNextInterval = () => {
                if (!this.keepPolling) {
                    this.stopPolling();
                    return;
                }
                this.interval = asyncTimeout();
            };

            Promise.resolve(promise)
            .then(assignNextInterval)
            .catch(assignNextInterval);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Navneet! How would I set the state in this situation?  I'm able to return the data from the server but my issue is setting the state here. The data comes from my API as an object with multiple key/value pairs but the way react-native-table-component is written, it only accepts an array of strings it appears.  I dug into react-native-table-component and updated my question with the code used in react-native-table-component to render the rows.  I suspect its because he/she is using a .map on the array but I'm not sure how to fix it.  If you have any suggestions that would be great!

Comment: Got it ... i have updated my answer on how to call set state and now you need to convert your response from multiple key/value to arrays.
you can do it like this ..
`tableData = [];
 for (var item in serverResponse) {
  tableData.push(item);
}`

Comment: if you face any problem converting array of array send me your key/value response in gitHub gist and i'll help you fix it.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure how to send the response in Github Gist, sorry!  It's almost working!  The only issue I'm having is that the for loop is pushing the keys to the array and not the values.  I want to only push the values to the array, without the keys.  

Any suggestions?  Thanks so much for all of your help so far!

Comment: Here's the code in Github Gist https://gist.github.com/BenjErgizerBunny/f4a839953b57ba8d8a94f7f2f08aa751

Comment: ahh.. got it  i have replied to your gist, hope it works..!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve it.

State Variable :

```js
this.state = {
    data: []
}
```

Another variable `widthArr` :

```js
const widthArr = [150, 150, 200, 100, 150]; // same length as your columns
```

After fetching data from api convert it to string using map :

```js
    const { data } = await axios.get(url, { headers: Api.headers }).catch((error) => {
      this.showError(error.message);
    });
    console.log(data.items.data);
    const records: [] = data.items.data;
    const rows = [];
    records.forEach((item) => {
      rows.push([
        item.name || 'Item',
        item.category,
        item.vendor_name,
        item.quantity,
        `$${item.price}`
      ])
    })
    this.setState({ 
      data: rows,  
      loading: false 
    });
```

Now you can use it in table as below :

```js
<Table
  borderStyle={{ borderColor: Colors.border }}
  style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
  textStyle={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'nunito' }}
>
  <Row
    data={["Product","Type", "Vendor", "Total Qty", "Total Price"]}
    style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}
    textStyle={styles.headText}
    widthArr={widthArr}
  />
  <Rows
    data={this.state.data}
    style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}
    textStyle={styles.rowText}
    widthArr={widthArr}
  />
</Table>
```